# while updating a html file and pushed to github its not updating

Tags: html, css

when I try to update  a html file, after that using git bash I have pushed a file and commit it, but the result is up-to-date. actually it is not updating

Admin@baluhari MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/working (master)
$ git add .

Admin@baluhari MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/working (master)
$ git commit -m "my changes"
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

the thing is want to show a updation in github

Comment: Type `git status` in the terminal and hit enter to see if you have any changes left to commit.

Comment: that option also I have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that You have git in your repository.
Write **cat "filename"** and it will show you what is in the file. By this simple instruction u can check which file git has and search the place where git takes files from. Then it`s obvious move file there or checkout git to other file.

After it
**git add .
git status (u will see what happened)
git commit -m "describe what u changed"
git push**

check of course do you have rights to push something into the branch

I hope u made
**git clone "link to your repostiory"**

and other first simple commands that appear after u create git repository on git hub

If, it won`t work check too does your editor has VCS(Version Control System). It`s easy to use. There are some buttons to connect, commit, clone, push etc

Answer (score 0):

You show that you commited to the branch but no log for the push

You need to run "git push -u origin branchname" actually push those commits from your local machine to the repository

Comment: actually I'm a beginner to github. but also I have pushed it but no result

Comment: Are you perhaps working from a fork of a repository?

Comment: so how can I rectify that

Comment: If you are working from a fork of a repository, be sure to view your fork inside github rather than the original repository to see your changes. Also be sure you are viewing the master branch. To merge that change into the original repository, you need to create a pull request from your fork into the original repo

Comment: its not working and its not from fork  of repository